# JList control size changes while running the jar file

Tags: java, swing, layout, jlist, gridbaglayout

I have two JList controls side by side. And few buttons in between them. The layout looks fine when I run from eclipse.

[image]

But if I run the exported jar file, the left occupies more space. I don't know why it's doing this.

[image]

I place them in a GridBagLayout like this.

```
mLstMdlTestSuitesAvailable = new DefaultListModel<String>();
mLstTestSuitesAvailable = new JList<String>();
mLstTestSuitesAvailable.setModel(mLstMdlTestSuitesAvailable);
mLstTestSuitesAvailable.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
JScrollPane scrollPaneTestSuitesAvailable = new JScrollPane(mLstTestSuitesAvailable);
GridBagConstraints gbcLstTestSuitesAvailable = new GridBagConstraints();
gbcLstTestSuitesAvailable.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gbcLstTestSuitesAvailable.weightx = 10;
gbcLstTestSuitesAvailable.gridwidth = 10;
gbcLstTestSuitesAvailable.weighty = 8;
gbcLstTestSuitesAvailable.gridheight = 8;
gbcLstTestSuitesAvailable.insets = new Insets(0, 11, 10, 11);
gbcLstTestSuitesAvailable.gridx = 0;
gbcLstTestSuitesAvailable.gridy = 1;
panel.add(scrollPaneTestSuitesAvailable, gbcLstTestSuitesAvailable);

mLstMdlTestSuitesSelected = new DefaultListModel<String>();
mLstTestSuitesSelected = new JList<String>();
mLstTestSuitesSelected.setModel(mLstMdlTestSuitesSelected);
GridBagConstraints gbcLstTestSuitesSelected = new GridBagConstraints();
gbcLstTestSuitesSelected.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gbcLstTestSuitesSelected.weightx = 10;
gbcLstTestSuitesSelected.gridwidth = 10;
gbcLstTestSuitesSelected.weighty = 8;
gbcLstTestSuitesSelected.gridheight = 8;
gbcLstTestSuitesSelected.insets = new Insets(0, 11, 10, 11);
gbcLstTestSuitesSelected.gridx = 15;
gbcLstTestSuitesSelected.gridy = 1;
JScrollPane scrollPaneTestSuitesSelected = new JScrollPane(mLstTestSuitesSelected);
panel.add(scrollPaneTestSuitesSelected, gbcLstTestSuitesSelected);
```

Can anyone please help me figure out what's going wrong here?

Comment: My initial guess is that the JRE configured with the system to run the JAR is different than the one Eclipse is using

Comment: Both of them use 1.7.0_45

Comment: Do yourself a flavour and use a decent LayoutManager,e.g. MiGLayout

Answer (score 1):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14429388/230513) for `JTable`, you can override the list's `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()` method to specify the initial, preferred size. Uisng a multiple of `getRowHeight()` offers a nice appearance.

[image]

Comment: Can you please give me a sample code of how you achieve this?

Comment: @KarthikAndhamil: The approach is also seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7881957/230513) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7225323/230513).

Answer (score 1):

The `GridBagLayout` respects the preferred sizes of the contained components. And the preferred size of a `JList` is determined by its contents. By looking at your screenshots it becomes clear that your `JList`s have different contents depending on the environment you are running in, therefore it’s not surprising that the preferred sizes differ.

If you want to have a more predictable behavior, have a look at [`setPrototypeCellValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setPrototypeCellValue(E)). This allows you to set a “typical value” which determines the cell size. The advantage over `setFixedCellWidth` is that it still respects fonts, display resolution, etc.

Comment: My bad. actually both of them launches with the same values. But user has options to change the values. So i took screen shots with different value. But, even if they are same, the size differs. You can look at the edited question now.

Comment: What’s interesting is that the height of the pictures differs. So you seem to enforce a height, e.g. via `JFrame`’s size. Then my guess is that the `GridBagLayout` switches between preferred and minimum size strategy. Try to change the frame’s size a bit and look what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why. A banner image at the top is not exported and so that made the mess in jar's layout. When i added the image to a folder where jar is exported to, then, it shows exactly same as the one run from eclipse. Thank you all.