# How to set different text color according to an enum in JList?

Tags: java, swing, enums, jlist, listcellrenderer

***EDIT : Here is the code updated after @HovercraftFullOfEels answer :***

note : I didn't use the HashMap, because I wanted to do several actions, like changing color and making the font bold or italic, and the HashMap provided in the answer only worked to set a specific color to a specific enum type.

so, here is the code :

```
package src;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import src.MainWindow.LogType;

public class MainWindow {

    public enum LogType {
        ERROR("Error"), COMMENT("Comment"), READ_INFO("Read_Info"), ACTION(
                "Action"), PARAM_ERROR("Param_Error");
        String text;

        private LogType(String s) {
            this.text = s;
        }

        public void setText(String s) {
            this.text = s;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }
    };

    private JFrame frmNavdng;
    private static DefaultListModel<LogType> logListModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
    private static JList<LogType> log_List = new JList<>(logListModel);

    public MainWindow() {
        initialize();
    }

    public static void add_Log_Line(LogType type, String s) {
        // add action to the log list
        type.setText(s);
        logListModel.addElement(type);
        log_List.ensureIndexIsVisible(log_List.getLastVisibleIndex());
    }

    private void initialize() {
        /** Frame Initialisation */
        frmNavdng = new JFrame();
        frmNavdng.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        frmNavdng.setTitle("list_window");
        frmNavdng.setResizable(false);
        frmNavdng.setBounds(100, 100, 640, 400);
        frmNavdng.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmNavdng.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(0, 0, frmNavdng.getWidth(), frmNavdng.getHeight());
        frmNavdng.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(log_List);
        log_List.setToolTipText("history of the last actions");
        log_List.setVisibleRowCount(10);
        log_List.setValueIsAdjusting(true);
        log_List.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
        log_List.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
                    window.frmNavdng.setVisible(true);
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
                        add_Log_Line(LogType.ACTION, ("loop " + i));
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.toString();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}

class MyCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyCellRenderer() {
        setOpaque(true);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value,
            int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        LogType lt = (LogType) value;   

        value = lt.getText();

        Color background = Color.white;
        Color foreground = Color.black;
        Font font = list.getFont();

        if (lt == LogType.ACTION) {
            foreground = Color.blue;
        }

        if (lt == LogType.COMMENT) {
            foreground = Color.darkGray;
        }

        if (lt == LogType.ERROR) {
            foreground = Color.red;
            font = new Font(list.getFont().getFontName(), Font.BOLD, list
                .getFont().getSize());
        }

        if (lt == LogType.READ_INFO) {
            foreground = Color.magenta;
            font = new Font(list.getFont().getFontName(), Font.ITALIC, list.getFont().getSize());
        }

        if (lt == LogType.PARAM_ERROR) {
            foreground = Color.orange;
            font = new Font(list.getFont().getFontName(), Font.BOLD, list
                .getFont().getSize());
        }

        if (isSelected)
            background = Color.lightGray;

        Component c = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

        c.setForeground(foreground);
        c.setBackground(background);
        c.setFont(font);

        return c;
    }
}
```

***EDIT 2 : Here is an illustration of what I get and what I would like to get :***

If I run the code given by @HovercraftFullofEels, slightly modified to change the text :

```
for(int i = 0; i<= 10; i++)
{
    LogType logType = LogType.values()[i];
    //just added this line
    logType.setText("Type : " + logType.toString() + " - Loop : " + i);
    logListModel.addElement(logType);
}
```

I get this result : 
[image: what I get by running the code]
each type of log get the last text given for each one... and it'd be great if they could get the text I gave them in the beginning so that after I could display text like "Failed to open the file" with the ERROR type and style, "The parameter given in this file is wrong, it will be ignored" with the READ_INFO style and type, and the "result written in the file result.txt" as an ACTION, for example.

With the code given, I don't get how and where I could set this text and make it to be "static" (meaning it won't change here).

**-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*- OLD QUESTION -*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-**

I am using a **JList** as a log viewer, and I'd like to have some lines added in different color.
For example, I have an `enum` with the types *COMMENT*, *ACTION* and *ERROR*. *COMMENT* will be in darkgrey, *ACTION* in blue and *ERROR* in red.

I tried to make a custom `ListCellRendered`, but I can't figure out how to set the different color according to the `enum`.

Here is my code :

```
public class MainWindow {
/* all the other declarations... */
private static JList<String> log_List;

/* configuration of the list somewhere in the code */
log_List = new JList<String>(new DefaultListModel<String>());
scrollPane.setViewportView(log_List);
log_List.setToolTipText("history of the last actions");
log_List.setVisibleRowCount(10);
log_List.setValueIsAdjusting(true);
log_List.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());

public enum LOG_TYPE {
    ERROR, COMMENT, READ_INFO, ACTION
};

// add action to the log list
public static void add_Log_Line(LOG_TYPE type, String s) {
//what I did before, but not working... 
/* if (type == LOG_TYPE.ERROR)  log_List.setForeground(Color.red);
    if (type == LOG_TYPE.ACTION) log_List.setForeground(Color.blue);
    if (type == LOG_TYPE.COMMENT) log_List.setForeground(Color.darkGray);
    if (type == LOG_TYPE.READ_INFO)log_List.setForeground(Color.magenta); */

    ((DefaultListModel<String>) log_List.getModel()).addElement(s);
    //makes the last raw visible after adding a line
    log_List.ensureIndexIsVisible(log_List.getLastVisibleIndex());
}

/* somewhere else in the code */
//add the path of a file chosen in a JFileChooser (fc)
add_Log_Line(LOG_TYPE.ACTION, "OPEN - " + fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());


/* My custom cell renderer */
class MyCellRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer<Object> {
public MyCellRenderer() {
    setOpaque(true);
}

public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value,
        int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

    setText(value.toString());

    Color background = Color.white;
    Color foreground = Color.black;

    if (value == LOG_TYPE.ACTION)
        foreground = Color.blue;
    if (value == LOG_TYPE.COMMENT)
        foreground = Color.darkGray;
    if (value == LOG_TYPE.ERROR)
        foreground = Color.red;
    if (value == LOG_TYPE.READ_INFO)
        foreground = Color.magenta;

    setForeground(foreground);
    setBackground(background);

    return this;
}
```

}

all I get is a black on white colored list...

Comment: `"I saw on other post that I could use the .setCellRenderer method, but I didn't really understand..."` -- that's the solution, the "easy" and the **only** solution. It's all demonstrated **with code** in the [JList Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html), and in example code that you can find here. Much better for you to check these examples,...

Comment: ... including [this near duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7881925/custom-listcellrenderer-will-not-change-background-color) as well as [these similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blistcellrenderer%5D+%5Bswing%5D+color)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels you're right... I edited the question with the custom cellRenderer I tried. I don't know how/where to check my enum value...

Comment: Hint: don't fill the JList model with strings but instead with enum items.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I don't understand what you mean... :/ shoul I change in this line `private static JList<String> log_List;` or something in this line `((DefaultListModel<String>) log_List.getModel()).addElement(s);` ? I don't really get where I can tell it to use the enum as an "design indicator" and the string as what to display in the list... or rather how to do both at the same time :/

Comment: You will use `JList<LOG_TYPE> log_List;` and `DefaultListModel<LOG_TYPE>`, and fill the model with LOG_TYPE objects. And of course `((DefaultListModel<LOG_TYPE>) log_List.getModel()).addElement(type);`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels okay, now the formatting is working, but with this,How do I put my string into the list then ? because now I have a list displaying "ACTION, READ_INFO, READ_INFO, READ_INFO, ...)

Comment: That's what your renderer getListCellRendererComponent method does. It can display a more pleasing String. You should only load the enum into the model, and consider using perhaps a `HashMap<LOG_TYPE, String>`  held by the model to get the appropriate display String for each LOG_TYPE.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I don't really understand how to use this HashMap, I get the principle, roughly, but don't know how to add it in my code to have the result I want... could you give me a little example of what you mean please ? :/

Comment: It doesn't have to be a HashMap. Shoot you can give the enum a String text field if you want, anything that allows you to associate an object (the log type) with a presentable String (the display in the JList) will do. That's all a HashMap or any map does -- associates one type of object, the key, with another, the value. I'm assuming that you've used Maps before, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you want to really add log types to the JList. I added a class called `LogEntry` and updated the code. See whether it helps.

```
package src;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

import com.sun.javafx.css.converters.FontConverter.FontStyleConverter;

import src.MainWindow.LogEntry;
import src.MainWindow.LogType;

public class MainWindow {

    public enum LogType {
        // @formatter:off
        ERROR("Error", Color.RED, Font.BOLD),
        COMMENT("Comment", Color.BLUE, Font.ITALIC),
        READ_INFO("Read_Info", Color.BLACK, 0),
        ACTION("Action", Color.YELLOW, 0),
        PARAM_ERROR("Param_Error", Color.RED, Font.ITALIC | Font.BOLD);
        // @formatter:on

        String text;
        Color color;
        int fontStyle;

        private LogType(String s, Color color, int fontStyle) {
            this.text = s;
            this.color = color;
            this.fontStyle = fontStyle;
        }

        public void setText(String s) {
            this.text = s;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }

        public int getFontStyle() {
            return fontStyle;
        }

        public Color getColor() {
            return color;
        }
    };

    public static class LogEntry {
        private LogType type;
        private String text;

        public LogEntry(LogType type, String text) {
            this.type = type;
            this.text = text;
        }

        public LogType getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public String getText() {
            return text;
        }
    }

    private JFrame frmNavdng;
    private static DefaultListModel<LogEntry> logListModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
    private static JList<LogEntry> log_List = new JList<>(logListModel);

    public MainWindow() {
        initialize();
    }

    public static void add_Log_Line(LogType type, String s) {
        // add action to the log list
        type.setText(s);
        logListModel.addElement(new LogEntry(type, s));
        log_List.ensureIndexIsVisible(log_List.getLastVisibleIndex());
    }

    private void initialize() {
        /** Frame Initialisation */
        frmNavdng = new JFrame();
        frmNavdng.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
        frmNavdng.setTitle("list_window");
        frmNavdng.setResizable(false);
        frmNavdng.setBounds(100, 100, 640, 400);
        frmNavdng.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmNavdng.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(0, 0, frmNavdng.getWidth(), frmNavdng.getHeight());
        frmNavdng.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(log_List);
        log_List.setToolTipText("history of the last actions");
        log_List.setVisibleRowCount(10);
        log_List.setValueIsAdjusting(true);
        log_List.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
        log_List.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
                    window.frmNavdng.setVisible(true);
                    LogType[] values = LogType.values();
                    for (LogType logType : values) {
                        add_Log_Line(logType, "This is log type " + logType.getText());
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.toString();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}

class MyCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyCellRenderer() {
        setOpaque(true);
    }

    @Override public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected,
            boolean cellHasFocus) {
        LogEntry entry = (LogEntry) value;

        value = entry.getText();

        Color background = Color.white;
        Color foreground = entry.getType().getColor();

        Font font = list.getFont();

        font = new Font(list.getFont().getFontName(), entry.getType().getFontStyle(), list.getFont().getSize());

        if (isSelected)
            background = Color.lightGray;

        Component c = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);

        c.setForeground(foreground);
        c.setBackground(background);
        c.setFont(font);

        return c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per our discussion, set the color in the renderer, and set the text there. Here I change the enum so that it returns a display String, but a HashMap works as well. I do use the HashMap to store the desired colors:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MainWindow extends JPanel {
   private DefaultListModel<LogType> logListModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
   private JList<LogType> logList = new JList<>(logListModel);
   private Map<LogType, Color> logTypeColorMap = new HashMap<>();

   public MainWindow() {
      logList.setPrototypeCellValue(LogType.COMMENT); // longest one

      for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
         int index = (int) (Math.random() * LogType.values().length);
         LogType logType = LogType.values()[index];// get a random LogType
         logListModel.addElement(logType);
      }

      logList.setVisibleRowCount(10);
      logList.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());

      add(new JScrollPane(logList));
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("MainWindow");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new MainWindow());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

enum LogType {
   ERROR("Error"), COMMENT("Comment"), READ_INFO("Read Info"), ACTION("Action"); 
   private String text;

   private LogType(String text) {
      this.text = text;
   }

   public String getText() {
      return text;
   }
};

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
   private Map<LogType, Color> logTypeColorMap = new HashMap<>();

   public MyCellRenderer() {
      logTypeColorMap.put(LogType.ACTION, Color.blue);
      logTypeColorMap.put(LogType.COMMENT, Color.darkGray);
      logTypeColorMap.put(LogType.ERROR, Color.red);
      logTypeColorMap.put(LogType.READ_INFO, Color.magenta);
   }

   @Override
   public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value,
         int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
      LogType logType = (LogType) value;
      Color color = logTypeColorMap.get(logType);
      value = logType.getText(); // extract text
      Component c =super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected,
            cellHasFocus);
      c.setForeground(color);
      return c;
   }
}
```

---

Problems with your code -- please see comments (using `\\ !!`) and corrections:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

//!! import src.MainWindow.LogType;

public class MainWindow {

   private JFrame frmNavdng;
   private static DefaultListModel<LogType> logListModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
   private static JList<LogType> log_List = new JList<>(logListModel);

   public MainWindow() {
      initialize();
   }

   // !! get rid of this method as it is doing you no good whatsoever
   public static void add_Log_Line(LogType type, String s) {
      // type.setText(s);
      logListModel.addElement(type);
      log_List.ensureIndexIsVisible(log_List.getLastVisibleIndex());
   }

   private void initialize() {
      frmNavdng = new JFrame();
      frmNavdng.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));
      frmNavdng.setTitle("list_window");
      frmNavdng.setResizable(false);
      frmNavdng.setBounds(100, 100, 640, 400);
      frmNavdng.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frmNavdng.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
      scrollPane.setBounds(0, 0, frmNavdng.getWidth(), frmNavdng.getHeight());
      frmNavdng.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
      scrollPane.setViewportView(log_List);
      log_List.setToolTipText("history of the last actions");
      log_List.setVisibleRowCount(10);
      log_List.setValueIsAdjusting(true);
      log_List.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 10));
      log_List.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer());
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
            window.frmNavdng.setVisible(true);
            for (int i = 0; i < LogType.values().length; i++) {
               // !! add_Log_Line(LogType.ACTION, ("loop " + i));
               // !! just add to the list model the actual LogType
               LogType logType = LogType.values()[i];
               logListModel.addElement(logType);
            }
         }
      });
   }

}

class MyCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   public MyCellRenderer() {
      setOpaque(true);
   }

   @Override
   public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value,
         int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
      LogType lt = (LogType) value;

      value = lt.getText();

      Color background = Color.white;
      Color foreground = Color.black;
      Font font = list.getFont();

      // !! note that you could hard-code the String held by value
      // here in these if blocks
      if (lt == LogType.ACTION) {
         foreground = Color.blue;
      }

      if (lt == LogType.COMMENT) {
         foreground = Color.darkGray;
      }

      if (lt == LogType.ERROR) {
         foreground = Color.red;
         font = new Font(list.getFont().getFontName(), Font.BOLD, list
               .getFont().getSize());
      }

      if (lt == LogType.READ_INFO) {
         foreground = Color.magenta;
         font = new Font(list.getFont().getFontName(), Font.ITALIC, list
               .getFont().getSize());
      }

      if (lt == LogType.PARAM_ERROR) {
         foreground = Color.orange;
         font = new Font(list.getFont().getFontName(), Font.BOLD, list
               .getFont().getSize());
      }

      if (isSelected)
         background = Color.lightGray;

      Component c = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index,
            isSelected, cellHasFocus);

      c.setForeground(foreground);
      c.setBackground(background);
      c.setFont(font);

      return c;
   }
}
```

Myself, I still like the way Maps condense code, making it easier to debug and use. For example, I'd consider doing something like this:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class MainWindow2 extends JPanel {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private static final Font FONT = new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.PLAIN, 12);
   private static DefaultListModel<LogType> logListModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
   private static JList<LogType> logList = new JList<>(logListModel);

   public MainWindow2() {
      Map<LogType, LogWrapper> wrapperMap = new EnumMap<>(LogType.class);
      wrapperMap.put(LogType.ACTION, new LogWrapper("Action", Font.PLAIN, Color.BLUE));
      wrapperMap.put(LogType.COMMENT, new LogWrapper("Comment", Font.PLAIN, Color.DARK_GRAY));
      wrapperMap.put(LogType.ERROR, new LogWrapper("Error", Font.BOLD, Color.RED));
      wrapperMap.put(LogType.READ_INFO, new LogWrapper("Read Info", Font.ITALIC, Color.MAGENTA));
      wrapperMap.put(LogType.PARAM_ERROR, new LogWrapper("Parameter Error", Font.BOLD, Color.ORANGE));

      for (int i = 0; i < LogType.values().length * 3; i++) {
         int index = i % LogType.values().length;
         logListModel.addElement(LogType.values()[index]);
      }

      logList.setToolTipText("history of the last actions");
      logList.setVisibleRowCount(10);
      logList.setValueIsAdjusting(true);
      logList.setFont(FONT);
      logList.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer2(wrapperMap));

      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(logList);
      add(scrollPane);

      logList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

         @Override
         public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
               JList<LogType> list = (JList<LogType>) e.getSource();
               LogType selection = list.getSelectedValue();
               String message = String.format("Selected LogType: %s", selection);
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainWindow2.this, message);
            }
         }
      });

   }


   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("MainWindow2");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new MainWindow2());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class MyCellRenderer2 extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private static final Color DEFAULT_BG = Color.WHITE;
   private static final Color SELECTED_BG = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
   private Map<LogType, LogWrapper> wrapperMap;

   public MyCellRenderer2(Map<LogType, LogWrapper> wrapperMap) {
      setOpaque(true);
      this.wrapperMap = wrapperMap;
   }

   @Override
   public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value,
         int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
      LogType lt = (LogType) value;
      LogWrapper logWrapper = wrapperMap.get(lt);
      String text = logWrapper.getText();

      Color background = isSelected ? SELECTED_BG : DEFAULT_BG;
      Color foreground = logWrapper.getForeground();
      Font font = list.getFont().deriveFont(logWrapper.getFontStyle());

      Component c = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, text, index,
            isSelected, cellHasFocus);

      c.setForeground(foreground);
      c.setBackground(background);
      c.setFont(font);

      return c;
   }
}

class LogWrapper {
   private String text;
   private int fontStyle;
   private Color foreground;

   public LogWrapper(String text, int fontStyle, Color foreground) {
      this.text = text;
      this.fontStyle = fontStyle;
      this.foreground = foreground;
   }

   public String getText() {
      return text;
   }

   public int getFontStyle() {
      return fontStyle;
   }

   public Color getForeground() {
      return foreground;
   }

}
```

---

If you trying to have unique text for each line in the JList then

1. make the generic type of the JList and its model the wrapper class.
2. change the wrapper to include the enum.
3. Create a unique wrapper instance for each item being added to the list, one with a unique text field value. A copy constructor can work well for this, if you want to set the font and color just once.

For example (code example 3):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class MainWindow3 extends JPanel {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private static final Font FONT = new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.PLAIN, 12);
   private static DefaultListModel<LogWrapper3> logListModel = new DefaultListModel<>();
   private static JList<LogWrapper3> logList = new JList<>(logListModel);

   public MainWindow3() {
      Map<LogType, LogWrapper3> wrapperMap = new EnumMap<>(LogType.class);
      wrapperMap.put(LogType.ACTION, new LogWrapper3("Action", Font.PLAIN, Color.BLUE, LogType.ACTION));
      wrapperMap.put(LogType.COMMENT, new LogWrapper3("Comment", Font.PLAIN, Color.DARK_GRAY, LogType.COMMENT));
      wrapperMap.put(LogType.ERROR, new LogWrapper3("Error", Font.BOLD, Color.RED, LogType.ERROR));
      wrapperMap.put(LogType.READ_INFO, new LogWrapper3("Read Info", Font.ITALIC, Color.MAGENTA, LogType.READ_INFO));
      wrapperMap.put(LogType.PARAM_ERROR, new LogWrapper3("Parameter Error", Font.BOLD, Color.ORANGE, LogType.PARAM_ERROR));

      for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < LogType.values().length; j++) {
            LogType logType = LogType.values()[j];
            LogWrapper3 wrapper = new LogWrapper3(wrapperMap.get(logType));
            String text = "Type : " + logType.toString() + " - Loop : " + i;
            wrapper.setText(text);
            logListModel.addElement(wrapper);
         }
      }

      logList.setToolTipText("history of the last actions");
      logList.setVisibleRowCount(10);
      logList.setValueIsAdjusting(true);
      logList.setFont(FONT);
      logList.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer3());

      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(logList);
      add(scrollPane);

      logList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

         @Override
         public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
               JList<LogWrapper3> list = (JList<LogWrapper3>) e.getSource();
               LogWrapper3 selection = list.getSelectedValue();
               String message = String.format("Selected LogType: %s", selection.getLogType());
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(MainWindow3.this, message);
            }
         }
      });
   }

   private class MyCellRenderer3 extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      private final Color DEFAULT_BG = Color.WHITE;
      private final Color SELECTED_BG = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;

      public MyCellRenderer3() {
         setOpaque(true);
      }

      @Override
      public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value,
            int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
         LogWrapper3 ltw = (LogWrapper3) value;

         Color background = isSelected ? SELECTED_BG : DEFAULT_BG;
         Color foreground = ltw.getForeground();
         Font font = list.getFont().deriveFont(ltw.getFontStyle());

         Component c = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, ltw.getText(), index,
               isSelected, cellHasFocus);

         c.setForeground(foreground);
         c.setBackground(background);
         c.setFont(font);

         return c;
      }
   }

   private class LogWrapper3 {
      private String text;
      private int fontStyle;
      private Color foreground;
      private LogType logType;

      public LogWrapper3(String text, int fontStyle, Color foreground, LogType logType) {
         this.text = text;
         this.fontStyle = fontStyle;
         this.foreground = foreground;
         this.logType = logType;
      }

      // copy constructor
      public LogWrapper3(LogWrapper3 lw3) {
         this.text = lw3.text;
         this.fontStyle = lw3.fontStyle;
         this.foreground = lw3.foreground;
         this.logType = lw3.logType;
      }

      public String getText() {
         return text;
      }

      public void setText(String text) {
         this.text = text;
      }

      public int getFontStyle() {
         return fontStyle;
      }

      public Color getForeground() {
         return foreground;
      }

      public LogType getLogType() {
         return logType;
      }

   }

   enum LogType {
      ERROR("Error"), COMMENT("Comment"), READ_INFO("Read Info"), ACTION("Action"), PARAM_ERROR("Param Error"); 
      private String text;

      private LogType(String text) {
         this.text = text;
      }

      public String getText() {
         return text;
      }
   };


   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("MainWindow2");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new MainWindow3());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the code, it works well, but the only part I don't get is, how to put the text I want in the list, other than just "comment" or "action". For example, I have the string "OPEN - File myfile.java" associated with the logType ACTION so written in blue, and I have the string "READ variable X of value 12 -> IGNORED" assiocated with READ_INFO type so written in magenta, etc. Sorry for being so slow, but that is the main point I don't really get :/

Comment: @KingKunu: I've already shown you how to change the color of a JList entry based on color above, and how to change the desired displayed String and again have written a small program that demonstrates this. If still stuck, then show your latest attempt, one that uses the information that I've posted above, and explain in detail in your edit to your original post how your current attempt isn't working. Also, please consider at least up-voting my answer if only for the time efforts that I have expended already in trying to help you.

Comment: Okay I just got how to do it. The thing was, even with your code, I didn't get how/where to set my text into the logType... I was a little confused. But I just tried a few moments ago to add a method `public void setText(String text){this.text = text;}` just like the constructor of the logType, and now it is working. Thank you ! I will update my code and edit my first post to make the solution available. And I did upvote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation score yet, so it's not visible, sorry :/

Comment: Okay... it's me again... I updated my code, and the text is displaying with the desired colors in the list, that's cool... the problem I have now is that all the fileds of the same category (COMMENT for example), are displaying the text of the last one added. (for instance, I add a line of type `COMMENT`, with the text `aaa`, it works well, but if I had after that a line of type `COMMENT` as well, with the text `bbb`, both the first and second lines are showing `bbb`...) I will edit my first post to show the updated code.

Comment: @KingKunu: please let me know when the code has been posted.

Comment: code posted. I posted only the concerned parts, hope it will be enough.

Comment: @KingKunu: much better to post a small complete, compilable program, one I can just copy and paste into my IDE and that works without change, much like what I posted above.

Comment: @KingKunu: this would mean including imports and including a main method. Preferably all the code would be in one file, meaning that the class with the main method would be public and all others would not. This way we could paste the code into a single File in Eclipse or NetBeans and it would run off the bat.

Comment: yeah you're right. I added the missing part in the question, it should run. Thanks.

Comment: @KingKunu: thanks for the code update; now please see my code updates.

Comment: Thanks for the code. But I am sorry, I think you didn't completely understand the main point of my question :/ I tested your code, and I can the "name" of the logtype it refers to, but what I would like to do is to be able to display whatever text I want coming from my program (like "Failed to open the file", "this parameter will be ignored", "Calculation is completed", etc.), with the color associated to the type of information it gives. like "Failed to open the file" would be in red because of the type ERROR, and the next one will be of type READ_INFO, and the last one will be a COMMENT.

Comment: I will update my question to try make it more visible

Comment: @KingKunu: my solution would still work fine -- just give the LogWrapper class a `setText(String text)` method, and then anywhere desired, set its text to whatever String is desired. Then have the renderer class use that text. I'll bet that you could figure this out on your own, please do give it a shot and let me know what you come up with.

Comment: I tried your solution, added a `setText(String text)` method to the LogWrapper class, and just before adding the item to the list (I tried just after too), I put this line `wrapperMap.get(LogType.values()[index]).setText("loop : " + i);` but the result is exactly the same.

Comment: @KingKunu: Are you trying to have unique text for each line in the JList? If so, then 1) make the generic type of the JList and its model the wrapper class. 2) change the wrapper to include the enum. 3) Create a unique wrapper instance for each item being added to the list, one with a unique text field value.

Comment: @KingKunu: please see latest (and hopefully final) edit to answer.

Comment: it worked ! thank you  ! and again sorry for the (big !) bother ! I didn't think my question would be such an pain in the *ss to solve :/ I learnt a lot of things with the answers you gave me :)